# SCSS: Calling a mixin inside another mixin?

Tags: sass

In the code below, I am trying to DRYing out SCSS by calling another SCSS/SASS mixin `padding-all()` inside `mybtn-structure()` mixin but SCSS wouldn't allow this and throws up errors.

```
@mixin padding-all($top: null, $right: null, $bottom: null, 
$left: null, $all: null) { 
         padding-top: $top;
         padding-right: $right; 
         padding-bottom: $bottom; 
         padding-left: $left; 
         padding: $all; }


@mixin mybtn-structure ($padding: null, $margin: 15px ) {
  padding: @include padding-all($padding);
  margin: $margin;
}

.cool-btn {
  @include mybtn-structure($padding: 12px, $margin: 10px)
}
```

I presume there must be a way to get what I am trying to do here. How can a mixin be called inside another mixin?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `padding` attribute in `mybtn-structure` mixin and call the mixin as follows:

```
@mixin mybtn-structure ($padding: null, $margin: 15px ) {
  @include padding-all($padding);
  margin: $margin;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, figured that out myself, just after posting this. However is it further possible to use `padding-all` arguments something like

`.cool-btn {
  @include mybtn-structure($padding: $top: 12px, $margin: 10px)
}`

Comment: Do you want to nest parameters? I didn't quite get what you need.

Comment: if you note, `@mixin padding-all($top: null, $right: null, $bottom: null, 
$left: null, $all: null)`  has parameters `$top, $bottom...` etc I want to use those parameters when calling the `mybtn-structure` mixin. e.g 
 `mybtn-structure($padding: $top: 12px)`

Comment: You can override the argument you want by using the same name and this should be propagated back to the mixin that is assigning the value to the attribute:


`@mixin foobar($topPadding: 10px, $rightPadding: 20px,
    $bottomPadding: 10px, $leftPadding: 20px, $evenMorePadding: 10px) {
    // do something with all these arguments...
}

p {
    @include foobar($bottomPadding: 50px);
}`

[See here](https://gist.github.com/jareware/4738651)